# Decision based game in unity with 2 Buttons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton, boolean

So I want to make a decision based game in Unity where there is text and you have to make some decisions with 2 Buttons. So I thought I could keep the same 2 buttons and if you press them you just turn their boolean true and based on the scenario in the code I just have to check for the boolean to be true and code what happens so that I dont have to use different buttons each time.

But the problem is if I just check instantly the player wont have time to press a button and nothing happens because both booleans are still false. Is there a way to wait until a button gets pressed and then check for the booleans?

Sorry that I cant provide any code because im on mobile rn.

Comment: How about rather make your code event driven and simply rather replace the callback assigned to the buttons? (`button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();` and `button.onClick.AddListener(() => {  ...});`)

Comment: Thanks I wil look further into that.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose there is a Script on each button attaching to
Button.onClick and setting the boolean to true, and the script handling your game also attaches to Button.onClick and checks the value, but it is getting called before the script on Button that is setting bool, right?
The easiest way to handle that would be playing with ScriptExecutionOrder.
FEG add 
[DefaultExecutionOrder(-9999)] to the script you want to be executed first.

Comment: no I dont think so the problem is that it checks immediately even if the player hasnt pressed a button so i want it to wait until the player chooses one option and then check for a button.